# hide accordion on condition with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app. And I try to hide an accordion on a condition - only visisble when a property has animals. But it seems it doesn't work.

So this is my component:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

import { ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { AccordionItemsContext } from "../../../services/accordion-items.context";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ButtonDetail } from "./animal-detail.screen";
import { CategoryList } from "./category.screen";
import { LoadingContainer } from "./category.screen";
import { MD2Colors } from "react-native-paper";
import { SafeArea } from "../../../components/utility/safe-area.component";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import { SubCategoryInfoCard } from "../components/subcategory-info-card.component";
import { ToggleContext } from "../../../services/toggle.context";
import { fetchSubCategoryData } from "../../../services/category/category.service";

export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [searchAnimal, setSearchAnimal] = useState("");

    //accordion

    const { toggle, showAccordion } = useContext(ToggleContext);
    const { accordionItems } = useContext(AccordionItemsContext);
    const isVisible = false;

    const handleSearch = (query) => {
        setSearchAnimal(query);
    };

    const filteredData = subCatgoryList.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchAnimal.toLowerCase())
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
            if (data.animals.length > 0) {
                setSubCategoryList(data.animals);

                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setSubCategoryList(data.subcategories);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }, [route]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {isLoading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Searchbar placeholder="Search" onChangeText={handleSearch} value={searchAnimal} />
            <CategoryList
                data={filteredData}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}
                                disabled={
                                    isLoading ||
                                    (!item.hasOwnProperty("animals") && !item.hasOwnProperty("subcategories"))
                                }>
                                <Spacer>
                                    <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                                </Spacer>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <View>
                                <ButtonDetail onPress={() => toggle(item.id)}>
                                    <AntDesign name="downcircle" size={24} color="green" />
                                </ButtonDetail>
                            </View>
                            {item.hasOwnProperty("animals") === true
                                ? showAccordion.includes(item.id) && accordionItems(item)
                                : !showAccordion}
                        </>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

and it is about this item:

```
{item.hasOwnProperty("animals") === true
? showAccordion.includes(item.id) && accordionItems(item)
: !showAccordion}
```

Because the accordion is now also visible when there is a sub category.

Question: how to show accordion only when item has animal property?

Comment: The condition has problem .Change it to `{item.hasOwnProperty("animals") && showAccordion.includes(item.id) && accordionItems(item)}
`